# multi-line command line in bash fails while equal one line command line succeeds

Tags: bash, docker, syntax

I try to figure out why the following command fails

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  --name somedb \
  -v "$(pwd)/database:/var/lib/mysql/" \
  -p "3306:3306" \
  -e MARIADB_USER=dbuser \ 
  -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=dbuserpwd \
  -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd \
  -d \
  mariadb:10.10-jammy
```

with the message:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
-e : commande introuvable    ## command could not be found in french
```

while the equivalent one line command line

```
docker run --rm --name somedb -v "$(pwd)/database:/var/lib/mysql/" -p "3306:3306" -e MARIADB_USER=dbuser -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=dbuserpwd -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd -d mariadb:10.10-jammy
```

succeeds.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space after your `-e MARIADB_USER=dbuser \`

[image]

This worked

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  --name somedb \
  -v "$(pwd)/database:/var/lib/mysql/" \
  -p "3306:3306" \
  -e MARIADB_USER=dbuser \
  -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=dbuserpwd \
  -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd \
  -d \
  mariadb:10.10-jammy
```